# How is it possible to uninstall the currently deployed app from phone within Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'd like to uninstall the app that I'm working on from within Android Studio instead of having to click SETTINGS -> APPS -> [name of app] -> UNINSTALL -> OK

Can that be done ?

Comment: Why do you require this uninstall from Studio ? are you using DB files that gets cached ? As such you could hit the play in Studio that would uninstall - then run the newer instance ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a terminal within Android Studio. You can find it in the bottom bar. Launch that sub-window and there run the `adb uninstall [your_app_package]` command.

Answer (score 0):

use the command `adb uninstall <package_name>` to do that